Issue with TCC/LE and Windows 11 24H2
I'm running the latest JPSoft TCC/LE available (14.00.9 x64) which started showing a system wide issue  after Windows 11 update to 24H2.
If I open a file with LIST, the mouse pointer starts moving with an hysteresis, like it's gliding on an ice surface (...). The motion of the pointer keeps going on some movements, making it hard to point at a specific point.
Note that even if I have the TCC/LE window in the background the pointer keeps being erratic anywhere - that gave me hard time understanding which was the origin!
When I quit the LIST command the mouse pointer returns to normal behavior.

The solution I found so far is by disabling mouse wheel support from OPTION dialog. Help text on that setting reports:

MouseWheel Support in LIST : Set mouse wheel support in LIST.  Disable
this option if you experience incompatibilities with other
applications.

Any other comment/solution is welcome!
